# Differentiate hadamard product of square matrix $S \odot VV^T \in R^{n \times n} $ over rectangular matrix $V \in R^{n \times r}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-equations, hadamard-product

I want to differentiate $f = \log\det(L)$ over $V$ where $L = S \odot VV^T$.

The thing that I know is $df = L^{-T} : dL = (S \odot VV^T) : (dS \odot VV^T+ S \odot (VdV^T+dVV^T ))$  where $:$is a Frobenius product and $\odot$ is a Hadamard product.

Maybe $dS$ is zero over $dV$ and $df =(S \odot VV^T) :  S \odot (VdV^T+dVV^T ) $ . But I don't know how to treat the Hadarmard product in trace.

I wanna get a solution in a matrix form, it's okay if it is derived in element wise form. But I don't want the solution including the $E$ and $B$ matrices.

How can i solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hadamard and Frobenius products commute with each other, i.e.
$$A\odot B:C = A:B\odot C$$
This property can be used to complete your derivation (assuming $dS$ is zero)
$$\eqalign{
df
 &= L^{-T}:dL \cr
 &= L^{-T}:S\odot(dV\,V^T+V\,dV^T) \cr
 &= S\odot L^{-T}:(dV\,V^T+V\,dV^T) \cr
 &= (S\odot L^{-T}+S^T\odot L^{-1}):dV\,V^T \cr
 &= (S\odot L^{-T}+S^T\odot L^{-1})V:dV \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial V} &= (S\odot L^{-T}+S^T\odot L^{-1})V \cr\cr
}$$

Comment: Would you let me know the reference of your derivation? My advisor want me to find a material explaining about it. Thanks!